# Retrieving data from the controllerApi method in the tsx file [Module Parse failed error]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core

I am trying to fetch some records from the database (through `ControllerApi`) and display them through `React`. Below is the code in the `*.tsx` file:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
class CourseData {
    courseId: number = 0;
    title: string = "";
}

const FetchCourses = () => { 

    const [courses, setCourses] = useState(0);

    fetch('api/Course/Index')
        .then(response => response.json() as Promise<CourseData[]>)
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({ empList: data, loading: false });
        });

    let contents = this.state.loading ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p> : this.renderCourseTable(this.state.empList);

    return <div>
        <h1>Courses</h1>
        {contents}
    </div>;
}
```

This code generates the following error:

[image]

I adopted this code from [this example](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51632.asp-net-core-2-0-crud-with-react-js-and-entity-framework-core.aspx).

I cannot see any syntax error, any ideas?

Below, I also share the `webpack.config.js` file

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: { 'main': './wwwroot/components/Main.tsx' },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: 'dist/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: "style-loader" },
                    { loader: "css-loader" }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: are you running webpack ?

Comment: @jgoday yes, I will include it in the OP

Comment: seems strange to see Main.tsx under wwwroot and not under ClientApp ...

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are missing a webpack loader to handle the tsx files

```
module: {
   rules: [
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, include: /wwwroot/components/, use: 'awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true' },
      { test: /\.css$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ use: 'css-loader?minimize' }) },
      { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
   ]
},
```